# How do I save a customized kendo UI grid to a dashboard for a specific user that is logged in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im building an asp .net MVC application that has a kendo grid. Users will be able to log in and customize the grid like group data using drag and drop or filter based on his/her needs. What I need to know is that is there an ability to save the changes a user makes to the grid so that the next time he logs in, he can directly see the customized grid instead of making the changes all over again.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way I can think of.

On Grid Events like group, select, sort fire a function that will collect grid properties as

```
JSON object
[{
sortable: true,
group : columnName,
OrderBy: asc
}]
```

1. call a event function
2. build a setting JSON object
3. Make a Ajax post to customer table
4. update `gridSettings varchar(Max)` field with the JSON object you built.
5. next time when customer logs in load grid properties from the field.